# Carddav server implementation

Tags: c#, carddav

I have to create a webservice for Carddav server implementation to provide contacts to Iphone after authentication.

I want to know the steps from start to end about url and parameter it will expect.

Means, at first it hit with url, username and password.

So, How i have to configure my methods and parameter?

I have readout the RFC links but still its not clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at [the documentation for Google's implementation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/carddav/).

For authentication, [use OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). If you need to supply your own OAuth authentication, look at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/).

For your REST Api, try to mimic Google's implementation which looks something like this:

Principal

```
https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/{userEmail}
```

Home Set

```
https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/{userEmail}/lists
```

Address Book

```
https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/{userEmail}/lists/default
```

Contact

```
https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/{userEmail}/lists/default/contactId
```

Comment: I think OAuth would not work with CardDAV and CalDAV server implementation with iOS client. iOS CardDAV client supports OAuth for Google server only, as far as I understand. You will need to use Basic or Digest auth in your server.